# Use different themes depending on route/component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use one theme across whole my application, apart of one page in which I would like to load another theme.

So far in my `main.scss` I am including a main theme

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$myapp-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-green, 50);
$myapp-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-green);

$myapp-light-theme: mat-light-theme($myapp-primary, $myapp-accent);
$myapp-dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($myapp-primary, $myapp-accent);

@include angular-material-theme($myapp-light-theme);
```

As you can see I declared to themes: `$myapp-light-theme` and `$myApp-dark-theme` and uses `$myapp-light-theme` as the main one. What I tried to do, to switch theme in my `home.component` (loaded into `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`) is place following code into components style (`home.component.scss`):

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import "../../styles/angular-material-theme";
@include angular-material-theme($myapp-dark-theme);
```

But this didn't work as I would expect. Is it even possible what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is, to wrap custom theme into extra class:

```
@include angular-material-theme($myapp-light-theme);
.dark-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($myapp-dark-theme);
}
```

Inside the component on which I want to turn on a custom theme:

```
  constructor(private overlayContainer: OverlayContainer, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('dark-theme');
    document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.remove('dark-theme');
  }
```